# How to keep alive a connection behind proxy in node js

Tags: node.js

I am sending a `https` GET Type request to an external API.

First, I created the `https` agent as below:

```
import https from 'https';

const KeepAliveAgent = new https.Agent( {
    keepAlive: true
} );
```

then set the request options as below:

```
let options = {
                url: 'externalapiurl',
                method: "GET",
                qs: queryString,
                agent: KeepAliveAgent 
            };
```

I just mentioned sample strings for url and qs, in the original request I am using the actual api url and querystring, then I am sending the request as below:

```
            console.time( "requestTime" );
            request( options, ( err, response, body ) => {
                if ( err ) {
                    logger.warn( err.message );
                }
                console.timeEnd( "requestTime" );
});
```

This is working fine, but I am printing the time taken for response above and this time is much more when I send the request behind a proxy, when I doesn't use proxy it's taking less than half second but with proxy it's taking around 3 secs, so it seems the "keep alive" is not working behind the proxy, how to make this work?
I tried same request using https-proxy-agent node module, but still the issue persists, appreciate any help.

Comment: What proxy are you talking about? Is it in the API server, in the client server, or external to both? Is the API url the same in both cases?

Comment: @vissi, please update the question with better details because current one quite unclear in terms of what the setup is

Comment: That was not my question, so I did not update it, but I am still interested
@Miguel, see below

Comment: @TarunLalwani
I have the following setup proxy client: HttpsProxyAgent or SocksProxyAgent; I also checked persistent-tunnel library, it can handle http keepalive, but does not handle proxy auth :(

Comment: I'm afraid the details about your setup are still a bit unclear, particularly when it comes to the proxy itself. I'll try to rephrase my question: where is that proxy installed? In the API server? In the client? In any case, I doubt `keep-alive` would have much impact on the response time, specially if you're making a single request. I would expect the proxy rerouting itself to affect it much more, as is apparently happening as per your explanation.

Comment: Based on the little understanding and clarity got from the question, When there is no proxy in between your client and the API definitely the server has to only serve your request, so it would always be on lesser side for time being taken. as soon as the proxy comes in between your vanila client and server, it has to do its job of routing/resolving/handling the incoming with the app server for a received server definitely there is an increase in the time.

Answer (score 1):

All about measuring performance of HTTP/HTTPS Proxies.  https://blog.thousandeyes.com/measuring-performance-with-http-proxies/][1]

Code given by you seems correct.
I suggest use socketio in nodejs for such implementation you are doing.